# getSession().getAttribute("...") = null?

Tags: java, jsp, сессия

Есть сервлет авторизации

```
@WebServlet(
    name = "SignInServlet",
    description = "Вход пользователя - проверка имени email и пароля",
    urlPatterns = {"/authorization_signin"}
    )
public class SignInServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

public SignInServlet(){
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    UserDataSet user = new UserDataSet();
    SignInModel modelSignIn = new SignInModel();


    user.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
    user.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));

    user = modelSignIn.doSignIn(user);

    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("loggedUser") == null) {
        if (user != null) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("loggedUser", user);             request.getRequestDispatcher("authorization.jsp").forward(request, response);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Email or password is incorrect");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }
    }

}

@Override
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
}
}
```

При авторизации переходим на страницу "authorization.jsp"

```
<body>
<%

if (request.getSession().getAttribute("loggedUser") != null){
    UserDataSet user = (UserDataSet) request.getSession().getAttribute("loggedUser");

    System.out.println("In author :" + request.getSession().getAttribute("loggedUser"));
%>
<h1> Hello <%= user.getFirstName() %> <%= user.getLastName() %>!</h1>
<h2>AUTORIZED!</h2>
 <a href="/authorization_logout">Log Out</a>
 <%
 }
else {
%>
 <h1>IDI DOMOI</h1>
 <%
}
 %>
 </body>
```

Браузер переходит на эту страницу и выводит указанные данные

НО, если ручками в строке URL перейти на localhost:8080
затем сразу попытаться перейти на "authorization.jsp"

то включится фильтр

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "LoginFilter")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
public void destroy() {
}



public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

    System.out.println("Enter filter");

    System.out.println("Filter session: " + httpRequest.getSession(false).getAttribute("loggedUser"));



    UserDataSet user = (UserDataSet) httpRequest.getSession(false).getAttribute("loggedUser");

    if (user != null) {
        System.out.println("CHAIN");
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    } else {
        httpResponse.sendRedirect("/");
        System.out.println("Not signin");
    }
}

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {

}

}
```

то фильтр скажет что сессия не существует
Не пойму почему она умирает...

Также если после авторизации ручками, через строку URL перейти на любую страницу *.jsp где проверяется сессия то сессии нет...

Что делаю не так ?

Comment: вот это `if (user != null)` совершенно бессмысленное условие, с таким же успехом можно написать `if(true)`, так как строкой выше вы создаете объект.

Comment: Этот код был скопирован мной, когда из БД получался юзер =) поэтому да, согласен.
Сейчас исправлю вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ был найден на англоязычном "собрате"

в JSP файлах нужно проверять сессию не через `request` - там его не будет, нужно проверять `session.getAttribute(...)`

[Линк на ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23167654/servlet-not-forwarding-session-attribute-to-jsp)